# JSON Data Grid like Excel in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am seeking a data grid such a excel sheet. My focus is on filter only(see mentioned image below)so please anyone can help in it.

[image]

Comment: You forgot to post the code

Comment: [Kendo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/index.html) has a pretty nice grid. @rpax: I'm pretty sure he doesn't have any. This question is only asking for a grid library (And as such, not really supposed to be on SO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery datagrid (http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/datagrid/)

Another one is http://handsontable.com/

But for advanced feature like excel have, you have to code it yourself or write a new plugin.

Comment: @Paul I already tested above grid but that doesn't meet the requirement as i posted snapshot above

Comment: Ok. Then I think you have to write your own plugin. But you can also check these 2 links, (http://paramquery.com/demos), (http://roberto.open-lab.com/2010/01/30/javascript-grid-editor-i-want-to-be-excel/)